# How to fetch value from variable in laravel?

Tags: php, variables, laravel-5, get, fetch

```
$product=ProductCatalog::where(['campaign_id' => $campaign_id])->get();
print($product);
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{"id":7,"campaign_id":64,"product_id":26,"created_at":"2018-03-20 10:29:51","updated_at":"2018-03-20 10:29:51"},{"id":8,"campaign_id":64,"product_id":27,"created_at":"2018-03-20 10:30:26","updated_at":"2018-03-20 10:30:26"}]
```

From $product i want to fetch value of product_id

How to fetch value from $product?

please help me with this problem...

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: Please check my answer, it will help you out to understand the laravel eloquent as well. Let me know if you still have any issues.

Comment: Glad to help you @bhoomiPatel , Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization) of eloquent as below.

> The `toArray` method converts the collection into a plain PHP `array`. If the collection's values are `Eloquent` models, the models will also be converted to arrays.

```
$product = ProductCatalog::where(['campaign_id' => $campaign_id])->get()->toArray();
```

And then you can access the array properties as per your need. See sample below.

```
foreach($product as $productValue) {
    print_r($productValue['product_id']);
}
```

Comment: Man, this is not an answer. She wants `product_id` from an array. Give your answer with her question.

Comment: @Virb, I've shown the idea to get the php array, everyone knows how to get the array data. But still I have updated my answer, you can check.

Comment: Why link to Laravel4.2 when OP is using Laravel5?

Comment: Thank you...@DarshanJain

Answer (score 0):

```
$productCatalogs = ProductCatalog::with('product')->where(['campaign_id' => $campaign_id])->get();
foreach($productCatalogs as $productCatalog){
    print_r($productCatalog->product);
}
```

This should work if you have defined relationship in ProductCatalog Model (ProductCatalog.php).